# AppDelegate never being called on iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app that runs on both ipad/iphone, so for ipad
I am using a view controller in `mainWindow_ipad.xib` and then I am loading a new view using navigation vc, but I cant access my `appDelegate` method. The app directly starts and loads  the newView which I am loading

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { }
```

How can I ensure this method is called? I am loading `mainWindow_ipad.xib` from `info.plist`

**Update**

this is my .m file

```
@implementation Ihope_test_sqlAppDelegate_iPad

@dynamic aNav;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
     NSLog(@"IPAD");// but i cant find this log output
}
```

this is my .h file

```
#import "Ihope_test_sqlAppDelegate.h"
@class RootView;
@interface Ihope_test_sqlAppDelegate_iPad : Ihope_test_sqlAppDelegate    

{ 
    IBOutlet UINavigationController *aNav;
}

//@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *usernameField;
//@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *passwordField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *aNav;
-(IBAction)removeKeyboard;
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the class of the app delegate in mainWindow_ipad.xib is of the right class. You need to make sure that the MainWindow nib file for iPad has an App Delegate that is of the `Ihope_test_sqlAppDelegate_iPad` class rather than `Ihope_test_sqlAppDelegate`.

Comment: In your `NIB/XIB` file, what class it the Application Delegate? It should be `Ihope_test_sqlAppDelegate_iPad` check that it isn't `Ihope_test_sqlAppDelegate` (or something like that).

Comment: plz check my .h class  i am using _ipad only

Comment: Have you checked the nib file? Add a log statement in `Ihope_test_sqlAppDelegate`'s `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` to see if that is being called

Comment: for iphone  NSlog works on hope_test_sqlAppDelegate   but not for ipad :(

Comment: (ignore last comment) What class is in the iPad's nib?

Comment: i am loading RootView class using navigation controller on ipadClass

Comment: Okay, do you have an App Delegate object in that nib? What class is that object? How did you create the nib?